# Как сказать вместо: "И для того, чтоб вам БОЛЬШЕ сюда хотелось приехать, нужно..."?

Tags: фразеология

Я понимаю, что фраза построена нелепо. Но что-то не могу подобрать варианты для более осмысленной формулировки. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как избавиться от ошибки?

Answer (score 3):

И для того, чтоб вам **сильнее** хотелось сюда приехать, нужно...

Answer (score 2):

Фраза, имхо, вполне корректна.

Дорогие будущие гости нашего санатория "Распутино"! Наш санаторий расположен в живописном историческом месте, неразрывно связанном с именем выдающегося деятеля русской сексуальной революции Григория Ефимовича Новых (Распутина). *И для того, чтобы вам больше сюда хотелось приехать*, мы приготовили вам пешую экскурсию "По гришкиным местам".

Если у вас другой смысл фразы, приводите её целиком. Еще лучше - с контекстом.

Comment: Понять можно, что пытались сказать, но порядок слов хаотичен: "сюда" оторвано от "приехать" и безо всякой надобности помещено между "больше" и "хотелось". В результате, смысл смещается в сторону мнимого: больше сюда, чем в загадочное другое место.

Answer (score 0):

(Можно просто слова переставить, но не совсем понятна ситуация: совсем ехать не хотят или хотят, но не спешат; что и кому "нужно" для этого сделать?)
"И чтобы вам ещё больше захотелось сюда приехать, нужно..."
"И чтобы вы загорелись желанием сюда приехать, нужно..."

Comment: Ситуация такова, что они (кто-то виртуальный) там ещё не были, им расписывают местные красоты одну за другой и призывают посетить это место. Вариант с "загорелись" подходящий. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Не удачно. Напрашивается: "и для того, чтобы вам больше сюда не хотелось". Лучше заменить. Может - "и для того, чтобы вам захотелось сюда приехать"... "еще сильнее захотелось приехать"

Answer (score 0):

И для того чтобы вам больше хотелось приехать сюда, нужно...